# How to create a Sphere using three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I was making a sphere using three.js but the output is just a black screen as shown.

[image: SphereBlankScreen]

The code I used is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My first three.js app</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r79/three.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            const scene = new THREE.Scene();
            const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

            const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 15, 32, 16 );
            const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffff00 } );
            const sphere = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            scene.add( sphere );

            camera.position.z = 5;

            function animate() {
                requestAnimationFrame( animate );

                sphere.rotation.x += 0.01;
                sphere.rotation.y += 0.01;

                renderer.render( scene, camera );
            };

            animate();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I couldn't explain why the code was unable to render the sphere. What went wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your camera is inside the sphere. Move it a bit further away from the origin like in the following live example:

```js
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
camera.position.z = 50;

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(15, 32, 16);
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: 0xffff00
});
const sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(sphere);

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  sphere.rotation.x += 0.01;
  sphere.rotation.y += 0.01;

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

animate();
```

```css
body {
      margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.143/build/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ahhh yes...definitely. Camera position was at position (0, 0, 5) while the sphere was centered at (0, 0, 0) with her radius r = 15. Camera was definitely swallowed by the sphere. Thank you!